# Unable to write command into connection Redisson

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisson

We are using Redisson verson 3.14.1, and we are getting 30k messages per second.
While doing so, we get the error with the trace

Caused by: org.redisson.client.WriteRedisConnectionException: Unable to write command into connection! Node source: NodeSource [slot=15540, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=null], connection: RedisConnection [entry=[commandsBatch=0, entry=[freeSubscribeConnectionsAmount=0, freeSubscribeConnectionsCounter=value:4027:queue:0, freeConnectionsAmount=24, freeConnectionsCounter=value:64:queue:0, freezeReason=null, client=[addr=redis://10.32.2.2:6379], nodeType=MASTER, firstFail=0], commandsBatchSemaphore=value:1:queue:0, sendWorkers=2, connectionsAmount=2], redisClient=[addr=redis://10.32.2.2:6379]], command: (EVAL), params: [local value = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]); if value == false then return nil; end; local t,..., 5, sessions{klM}, redisson__timeout__set:sessions{klM}, redisson__idle__set:sessions{klM}, redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:sessions{klM}, sessions{klM}:redisson_options, 1660919795305, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 38, cap: 256)] after 3 retry attempts
at org.redisson.command.RedisExecutor.checkWriteFuture(oh:279)
... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(Object, ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)
"
thread_name: "redisson-netty-3-14"
traceId: "27c3b4124840b2d5"
}
Can anyone help me to know what are we doing wrong?